# Cannot find symbol when initializing a class in an if statement java

Tags: java

I am initializing a character based on player input choosing 3 classes, but when I run the program using any function from these classes, I get an error saying that it cannot find the symbol "user" in line 46 of main.java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String name = userInput.nextLine();
    HashMap<String, Integer> inventory = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    String equippedItem = "Simple Sword";
    int playerStrength = 3;
    while(true){
      //assign variables
      System.out.println("What class are you?\nWarrior | Archer | Mage\n(Type 'help' for an explanation of the classes)");
      String playerClass = userInput.nextLine();
      if(playerClass.equals("help")==true){
        System.out.println("Each class has a different set of weapons that can be equipped, ");
        continue;
      }
      else if(playerClass.equals("Warrior")==false && playerClass.equals("Archer")==false && playerClass.equals("Mage")==false){
        System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
        continue;
      }
      else if (playerClass.equals("Warrior")==true){
        Warrior user = new Warrior(name);
        inventory.put("Simple Sword",10);
        equippedItem = "Simple Sword";
      }
      else if (playerClass.equals("Archer")==true){
        Archer user = new Archer(name);
        inventory.put("Simple Bow",10);
      }
      else if (playerClass.equals("Mage")==true){
        Mage user = new Mage(name);
        inventory.put("Simple Fireball",10);
      }
      else{
        System.exit(100);
      }
      int enemNum = 0;
      while(true){
        enemNum = enemNum + 1;
        int weaponStrength = inventory.get(equippedItem);
        int enemyDamage = enemNum*10;
        int enemyHealth = enemNum*400;
        int playerDamage = user.getDMG(playerStrength, weaponStrength);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Even if I put an else statement automatically defining the user as a warrior it gives me the same error. It only works if I remove the if statements and place a definition of the character as a warrior.

Comment: Assuming `Warrior`, `Archer` etc. all inherit from a common class you should declare a variable of said class type before your `if...else....` statements and assign `new Warrior`, `new Archer` etc to that variable.